# sql using different execution plans when running a query and when running that query inside a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, t-sql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have this query,

```
Declare @Prcocessrate float
declare @item varchar(20)
declare @process varchar(20)
declare @branch varchar(20)
set @item = 'shirt'
set @process = 'kt'
set @branch = '1'
select @Prcocessrate =  ProcessPrice from itemwiseprocessrate where itemname=@Item and Process=@process and branchid=@branch
```

when I run it single handed, the execution plan only shows **3 steps**, see for youself..

[image]

but I have this `procedure` `sp_newBooking` as

```
ALTER PROC sp_newbooking
-- other arguements--
AS
BEGIN

--OTHER FLAGS--

ELSE IF (@Flag = 32)
        BEGIN

            declare @ItemId varchar(max),@ProcessRate float
            --set @BranchId='1'
            select @ProcessCode = DefaultProcessCode from mstconfigsettings where branchid=@BranchId
            select @ItemId= DefaultItemId from mstconfigsettings where branchid=@BranchId
            select @ItemName=  ItemName from itemmaster where itemid=@ItemId and branchid=@BranchId
            select @ProcessRate =  ProcessPrice from itemwiseprocessrate where itemname=@ItemName and ProcessCode=@ProcessCode and branchid=@BranchId
            if(@ProcessRate is not null)
            select @ItemName as ItemName,@ProcessCode as ProcessCode,@ProcessRate as ProcessRate
            else
            select @ItemName as ItemName,@ProcessCode as ProcessCode,'0' as ProcessRate
        END

-- OTHER FLAGS --


END
```

Now!, when I run this

```
exec sp_newbooking
@flag = 32,
@Branchid = 1
```

The execution plan is showing **6 steps!** Here's the picture..!
See the **query 4**[image]

**Why is it taking 6 steps to perform the same query** when executing from the procedure, while its taking 3 steps when executing alone? Wtf is this?

Comment: Probably an implicit cast. What is the compute scalar doing in the second plan? (look in the properties window for this). Are the stored procedure parameters the same datatypes as the variables in the first query?

Comment: I think @MartinSmith is correct. When you are running the query outside the proc, your are using a varchar(20) type for @branch with a value '1'. When you call the proc you are specifying @branchid = 1. See no quotes around the 1 there. SQL Server is converting the value 1, which is an int, to a varchar when calling your sp. I'd suspect if you call your SP as `EXEC sp_newbooking @flag=32, @branchID='1' ` you would get identical execution plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of reasons SQL can use different execution plans.  It could be :

- Different parameters for the same queries (you use constants in your first example, the queries in the 2nd might have different values)
- Different data (meaning you're running queries on dev & production)
- Parameter sniffing -- more below, but first pass the procedure might have the 'desired' parameters
- Different data types - as @MartinSmith points out, we don't see the parameter declarations.  You could have a variable that doesn't match the type of the field it's matched up against.

**Parameter Sniffing**
Stored procedures do '[parameter sniffing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439.aspx)' which is a blessing (if it works for you) and a curse (if it works against you). First pass someone searches on `Zebr%` for zerbrowski.  The last name index realizes this is very specific and will return, lets say, 3 rows from a million -- so one execution plan is built. With the proc compiled for a low row result, the next search is for `S%`.   Well, S is your most common name and matches 93,543 rows out of 1 million.

**So what can you do?**
There are lots of steps you can take to inspect this....

- Look carefully at the variable data types, comparing your ad hock query, the proc, and the underlying table (sp_columns *mytable*).
- Isolate the moving parts

  - Make sure you're running in both queries in the same system with the same data
  - Have a trace running to make sure first run of the proc uses the expected parameters
  - Try running your ad hock query with a few different parameters and see how the execution plan changes.
  - If you can't isolate activity, temporarily add `WITH RECOMPILE` to the proc to compare execution plans.  Alternately, do a `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` just before running.  (**DISCLAIMER - if this is a live system make sure you understand what these will do**).